# Where is the best place to define environment variables in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables

I have Ubuntu 10.04. I want to define some environment variables that will be available anywhere, anytime, including from Eclipse. Where is the best place to put them? ~/.bashrc? ~/.profile? /etc/environment?

Why are there so many places to define settings?

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? What window manager?

Comment: I use gnome desktop. How can I know what window manager I use?

Comment: @Erel: If you're using a full DE such as GNOME or KDE, the window manager is not important. *(GNOME uses either Metacity, Compiz, or Mutter.)* It only makes a difference when the WM is being used standalone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~/.profile` might be the best place – it is read for graphical logins (GDM), console logins, and even SSH. (The latter two only if neither `~/.bash_profile` nor `~/.bash_login` exists, though... but GDM *always* reads it.)